# "use" throwing class not found in Laravel 5, despite having it in that namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I try to route a `GET` Request for `Candidates\{candidate}` like so:

```php
// web.php
Route::get('/candidates/{candidate}', 'Controller@show_candidate');
```

to which the controller passes the variable to the `View`

```php
// Controller.php

// Other default imports omitted
use App\Commons\Candidates\Candidates; // Notice that it accesses the class inside the file

public function show_candidate($candidate){
        return view('pages.candidate', ['candidate' => Candidates::$$candidate]);
    }
```

which is using a `Candidate.php` class:

```php
namespace App\Commons\Candidates;

abstract class Candidates{
    const biden = "Joe Biden";
    const sanders = "Bernie Sanders";
    // ...
}
```

so when I enter a url like `/candidates/biden`, I would get for my `$candidate` `Joe Biden`.

However, it gives me a `Class App\Commons\Candidates\Candidates Not Found` error. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: @fmsthird It's a `variable-variable`, so if the query is `$candidate` is `biden`, `$$candidate` would be `$biden` so it would be `Joe Biden`.

Comment: Your name space should similar to your project folder structure, does your `Candidates.php` file place in the folder `App->Commons->Candidates`? if the file is inside the folder `Commons`, the namespace of the `Candidates` class should only be `App\Commons`

Comment: @catcon Yeah, the file `Candidates.php` is in `app/Commons/Candidates.php`, which is so far the only file in the `commons` folder.

Comment: so, it should be `namespace App\Commons;` in your `Candidates.php` file

Comment: @catcon Works, thanks!

Comment: No worries, mate!